# За счёт чего глобальная переменная окружения PATH "склеивается" с заданной для конкретного пользователя и как этот механизм может поломаться?

Tags: windows, windows-service

На сервере имеются следующие системные настройки:

- Системная переменная PATH - c:\foo
- Пользовательская переменная PATH - c:\bar

Если войти на сервер по RDP и запустить командную строку, то можно увидеть:

```
c:\> set path
PATH=c:\foo;c:\bar
```

То есть две настройки "склеились" через точку с запятой и всё работает.

Но при этом системная служба, запущенная от имени того же самого пользователя, видит окружение вот так:

```
PATH=c:\bar
```

Замечу, что если удалить пользовательскую переменную среды - службе становится видна общесистемная:

```
PATH=c:\foo
```

Как такое вообще может быть?

---

Дополнительная информация если это важно. Системная служба - это сборочный агент Bamboo, написана на Java.

Comment: Когда запускается служба то **НЕ** грузится профиль пользователя, в котором и прописаны переменные ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬСКОГО окружения.Кстати, если запустите подсказку к команде runas - увидите возможные варианты исполнения команд с загрузкой профиля и без.

Comment: Path обрабатывает Explorer, который при загрузке получает системный Path от userinit и загружает пользовательский Path. Системная служба запускается без загрузки общего профиля, потому что "под ней" нет userinit. Картина строго обратна той, которая наблюдается при старте приложения через RunAs с ключом /noprofile.

Comment: @Daemon-5 если бы профиль пользователя **совсем** не грузился - я бы увидел `PATH=c:\foo`. А он грузится, но грузится как-то неправильно...

Comment: Я этого не говорил. Наоборот - пользовательский профиль для службы как раз загружается. А вот общий - нет. Смотрите внимательнее, кто и что пишет.

Comment: @Akina это было бы похоже на правду, если бы я не видел системной переменной среды в логах (см. новую редакцию вопроса)

Comment: Хм. Не приходилось мне сталкиваться с удалением Path из пользовательского профиля... Тогда остаётся предположить, что explorer делает append, тогда как svchost тупо грузит непустую переменную профиля, а при отсутствии оставляет как есть - т.е. то, что осталось от загрузки системного (или группового?)... но рыть доки и искать истину мне, признаться, лениво.

Comment: @Akina тогда уж не svchost, а services.exe. Первый никогда не использовался java-службами

Comment: Вообще тут идет [разбор](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126512/how-are-windows-environment-variables-evaluated), и упоминается, что пользовательская переменная МОЖЕТ перекрыть системную. И [тут](http://superuser.com/questions/867728/)

Answer (score 0):

Пользовательские переменные имеют преимущесто перед системными, т.е. первая перепишет последнию.

Но одно исключение, переменная PATH составяется из системной и пользовательской переменной PATH, причём последняя добавляется к первой, т.е. пути из системной переменной здесь имеют преимущесто.

Comment: Вы вообще вопрос читали? В том-то и проблема, что переменные не хотят склеиваться.